# What is the difference between North Eastern Council (NEC) and other zonal councils of India?

Tags: india

The zones created for the administration of Indian states region wise didn't comprise North-Eastern states, for their development a special North Eastern Council was set up in 1971, what is the fundamental difference between other zonal councils and NEC.

Also everywhere including Wikipedia ([link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonal_Council)) it is mentioned that NEC is a statutory body, how if all the councils are formed by the central government acts (though different acts) makes one a statutory body while others are not?

Comment: Have you read this? https://mha.gov.in/zonal-council

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know that how North-eastern council is different from other zonal councils, is it just another council like other zonal councils just formed by a different act, or is it altogether a different kind of organization with different kinds of powers